# Where to create a basic class in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to create a wrapper/decorator class that I pass a model into and get a class with formatted output fields back.

Where is the best place for that to go?

I have it in the models folder but my spidey sense is tingling to look more into it.

Comment: is there a standard format that will be shared by multiple models? When you say formatted. What type of format are you referring to?

Comment: It's just for one specific purpose really.  I have a model and have a single specific use case for that model that uses differently formatted output.

Comment: where/how will the data be displayed? In a view? What differences are there from the standard model structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convention for decorators would be `/app/decorators`

This is basically the case for [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) classes

Answer (score 2):

you say formatted.
IMHO `YourModelPresenter` is a good name (more descriptive I think than `Decorator`), and then I would put it in `app/presenters`

Comment: debates are quite endless: presenter vs decorator

Comment: Maybe. I came from C# world and there Presenter is rather used when formatting for UI purposes.

Comment: @R_O_R Unfortunately I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

These days, the best practice I have seen is to create a directory under `app/` which follows the name of your project.  Generally this is the "domain" directory for classes which are specific to your app.

For example, if your project name is "blog", you'd create a directory called `app/blog`. Then, you can create subdirectories and namespace classes appropriately for organization.

Further example:  To create a `PostDecorator`, you could have:

`app/blog/decorators/post_decorator.rb`

Which would look like:

```
module Blog
  module Decorators
    class PostDecorator

      #code

    end
  end
end
```